# SCD and command task is not working

Tags: ssis, scd

Slowely changing dimension task is not working in data flow task.. but if I remove it and use the OLEDB destination it is inserting the data. I have no idea why it is not inserting data into the table. SCD and leaf task is also not converting to yellow or green color.

I have to do insert & update on the table based on two columns.

This is what I have tried:

- When I have used only OLEDB destination - everything works fine
- When I am doing look up and sending matched output to command task (where I am using the update command) and no match to OLEDB destination - nothing works.
- When I am using SCD and using two columns as business key and other as changing attribute - nothing works.

with "nothing works" I mean, even these task are not converting in yellow or green.

Any idea what could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Even when you get it to work, you will realise that it's slow as hell and missing lots of configuration options.

Therefore I recommend [this](http://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/) handy component initiated and recommended by the godfather of ETL & data warehousing, [Ralph Kimball](http://www.amazon.de/Kimballs-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Classics/dp/0470479574).

I personally will never return to the SSIS standard component. Try it, it's awesome.

Comment: I'd like to say that's true - but it isn't (your Kimball comment).  They asked me to remove their name from it.  But your remainder is totally true - I'm also sure that the SCD Wizard component is actually working - it's just hard to see grass growing.